# How to get sum of all elements of given list using list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

```
l = [5, 7, 8, 2, 1, 4]

sum = 0
for i in l:
    sum += i

print(sum)
```

how can I get sum of all elements but using list comprehension?

Comment: Why not `sum(l)` ?

Answer (score 2):

`list comprehension` should be used only for generating a `list`. You can simply use `sum(l)`.

Answer (score 2):

List comprehension always produces another list so I am not sure if you can even do that. You will surely need other function to fold the sequence into a single value.